# Foundation 4 orbit error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation, orbit

[Error message http://puu.sh/3ip7L](http://puu.sh/3ip7L)

This error is appearing for me constantly. If I upload the foundation.4.2 folder directly the index.html file runs fine, but as soon as I try to access them from anywhere else, I get the orbit error.

Here is some of the code:

Calling modernizr.js

```
<script src='<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js'></script>
```

Getting Zepto/jquery:

```
    <script>document.write('<script src=<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/js/vendor/' +
  ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery') +
  '.js><\/script>')
  </script>
```

Calling foundation.js and orbit.js

```
      <script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js"></script>
```

and then I initialize foundation and call orbit.js.

```
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#featured').orbit({ fluid: '2x1' });
});
</script>
```

Yet for some reason the error persists. Can someone help please?

Comment: Your path must be wrong. check the paths in "inspect element"

Comment: When I mistype the paths, I get an error that the file doesn't exist, so I've got the paths right. It also works in files in the same directory, which has the same code.

Comment: Do you have a link or you run this on localhost?

Comment: Running on localhost.

Comment: Are you sure this is right? /js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js because looking at this /js/foundation.min.js it makes me wonder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a sample Orbit. You can modify it as you need or just delete the body entirely and rewrite your code (don't delete the Js tho). Not sure what is exactly wrong with your code but the last Js snippet doesn't look right to me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Foundation 4</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />

  <script src="js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-10 large-centered columns">
        <ul>
          <li><img src="img/banners/1.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="img/banners/2.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="img/banners/3.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="img/banners/4.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="img/banners/5.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  document.write('<script src=' +
  ('__proto__' in {} ? 'js/vendor/zepto' : 'js/vendor/jquery') +
  '.js><\/script>')
  </script>
  <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).foundation();
  </script>
</body>
</html>`
```